# How to see progress of mongorestore?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

Is there any way to get a progress measure or remaining time estimate from `mongorestore`?

I used `mongodump` to export a compressed archive, which generated an 8GB file in about an hour and showed a progress bar, and now I'm trying to load the archive on a separate staging server. However, even though the dump contains no indexes, the restore has been running for over 6 hours.

My restore command is simply:

```
mongorestore --drop --gzip --archive=dumpfile
```

From what I've read, mongorestore is terribly inefficient, so long restore times is a common complaint. However, it would be nice to know if I have to wait a few more hours vs a few more days.

The manpage doesn't list anything like a `--progress` option. Is there any way to get even a rough estimate for the remaining restore time?

Comment: Did you check in the log file?  Also there are other ways to copy database other than mongodump and mongorestore.

Comment: with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-verbose verbose argument you see document counts. But not a progress bar as we know it. After the restore completed he will build indexes and there you see the progress in `mongodb.log`

Comment: Not directly but if you know a bit of programming especially golang you can do so.